# EPPlus Pivot table change order in Column fields

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, epplus-4

I'm using EPPlus (4.1.1) to create a Pivot table on a sheet. All goes well except I have no control on the order of the specified column field ("Wait Delay") and the data fields ("Values") in the "Columns" section (see attached image). In Excel this can be set by the Position property of the DataPivotField of a PivotTable:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataPivotField
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

Within Excel in the PivotTable Fields Task Pane this has the result the DataPivotField == "Values" is on top of the Columns area:

[Changing position of DataPivotField (="Values")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FntE5.png)

How can this be done in EPPlus.  The DataPivotField always appear as the last element in the "Columns" section.